# Save a Bitmap with Text from a textbox in C#

Tags: c#, text, bitmap, picturebox, savefiledialog

I want to be able to save a bitmap image with text from a text file so when i open it both the text and bitmap file open and can be viewed at a later date. This is my current code for saving a bitmap image:

```
{
    //Show a save dialog to allow the user to specify where to save the image file
    using (SaveFileDialog dlgSave = new SaveFileDialog())
    {
        dlgSave.Title = "Save Image";
        dlgSave.Filter = "Bitmap Images (*.bmp)|*.bmp|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
        if (dlgSave.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            //If user clicked OK, then save the image into the specified file
            using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(capturebox.Width, capturebox.Height))
            {
                capturebox.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height));
                bmp.Save(dlgSave.FileName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So i need it to save the text in a label called ExtraNotes and then be able to open the image in the picturebox (capturebox) and the text in the label again. Please Help,

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will draw a rough text (you can make it prettier):

```
static void DrawSomethingToBitmap(Image img, string text)
    {
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(img);
        g.DrawString(text, SystemFonts.DefaultFont, Brushes.Gray, 
            img.Width/2, img.Height/2);

    }
```

Just call

```
DrawSomethingToBitmap(bmp, lblMyLabel.Text);
```